# Android Fragment uses full path for import

Tags: java, android

Using a Fragment, Android requires the full path name to declare type for a class that I am utilizing. (Using Android Studio - this is the path found by autocomplete.)

For example:

- "com.example.myapp.MyClass" instead of just "MyClass".

Why is this? What is happening here? I find it strange because the Fragment is in the same package as these other classes.

(Edited to remove error.)

Comment: Sounds like the `package` is wrong in the Fragment file

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Thanks, the Confirm interface was declared improperly. I've edited the question to remove that.

Answer (score 0):

Check in your settings under Editor>CodeStyle (Java/Kotlin) in the "Imports" tab if "Use Fully qualified class names" is unchecked. Also try rebuilding the project.

Comment: It is unchecked, and I have rebuilt it, but I still get an error if I try to use "MyClass".